# How to append options to select in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My select menu is just created before appending the options, How can I append options variable to this select. Also I have multiple select of this class

```
        var options;
        $.each( generalPreset, function( key, value ) {
            console.log(value.description);
            options = options + '<option>'+value.description+'</option>';
        });
        $field.closest('.body-row').find('.item-description').html(`
        <select class="form-control general-presets" name="description[]" required style="flex: 1">
            <option></option>
            `
            + $('.general-presets').append(options) +
            `
        </select>
        `);
```

Comment: Are you expecting a string of `<option>` elements where you concatenate `$('.general-presets').append(options)`? Why? `options` _is_ that string you’re looking for. `$('.general-presets')` is the `<select>` you’re currently defining the HTML of, so you can’t select it at this point.

Comment: What will be the other solution?

Comment: `options` is already a string, and you're building a string, so simply: `.html("<select ...><option></option>" + options + "</select>")`  [expanded to an answer below]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `options` variable is already a string and you're building a new string, you can simply concatenate them together:

```
        var options;
        $.each( generalPreset, function( key, value ) {
            console.log(value.description);
            options = options + '<option>'+value.description+'</option>';
        });
        $field.closest('.body-row').find('.item-description').html(`
        <select class="form-control general-presets" name="description[]" required style="flex: 1">
            <option></option>
            `
            + options +
            `
        </select>
        `);
```

If you're intent on using `.append()` then the `.html("new html")` call can be chained with more jquery instructions, for clarity it would be:

```
var itemdesc = $field.closest('.body-row').find('.item-description');
itemdesc.html("<select.... </select>");
itemdesc.find("select").append(options);
```

or chained

```
$field.closest('.body-row')
      .find('.item-description')
      .html("<select.... </select>");
      .find("select")
      .append(options);
```

Answer (score -1):

How about native api?

[Option() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option)

```
$field.closest('.body-row').find('.item-description').html(`
  <select class="form-control general-presets" name="description[]" required style="flex: 1"></select>
`);

$('.general-presets').each(function() {
  generalPreset.forEach(function(value) { this.add(new Option(value.description, '')); });
});
```